# ERROR: _this2.state.progress is not a function. (In '_this2.state.progress(false)', '_this2.state.progress' is 99.98701624033674)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, constructor, progress

ERROR: _this2.state.progress is not a function. (In '_this2.state.progress(false)', '_this2.state.progress' is 99.98701624033674)
my progress bar works only up to 99%, when it arrives at 100% shows this error message. my progress bar works only up to 99%, when it arrives at 100% shows this error message. Can anyone help me with this ? I'm trying to fix it, but I can't

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
    import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';
    
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { progress: 0 };
      }
      startProgressIndicators() {
        let progress = 0;
        this.setState({ progress }, () =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ indeterminate: false });
            setInterval(() => {
              progress += Math.random();
              if (progress <= 100) {
                this.state.progress;
              } else {
                this.state.progress(false);
              }
              this.setState({ progress });
            }, 500);
          }, 1500)
        );
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>indicador de progresso</Text>
            <View style={{ margin: 5 }} />
    
            <Button
              title="Iniciar"
              onPress={() => this.startProgressIndicators()}
            />
    
            <View styles={{}}>
              <Text>{`${this.state.progress.toFixed(0)}%`}</Text>
            </View>
    
            <Progress.Bar
              size={50}
              progress={this.state.progress / 100}
              width={200}
              style={{ margin: 5, fontSize: 10 }}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      text: {
        color: '#051923',
        margin: 10,
        fontSize: 30,
      },
    });
    
    export default App;
    
    {
      /* <Progress.Bar progress={0.3} width={200} />
    <Progress.Pie progress={0.4} size={50} />
    <Progress.CircleSnail color={['red', 'green', 'blue']} /> */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct - there is no function called `this.state.progress`.  You've defined it here:

`this.state = { progress: 0 };`

so `this.state` is an object with a key called `progress`, which holds a value of `0`.  You can't call it like you would do with a function.

This block is confusing to me:

```js
      startProgressIndicators() {
        let progress = 0;
        this.setState({ progress }, () =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ indeterminate: false });
            setInterval(() => {
              progress += Math.random();
              if (progress <= 100) {
                this.state.progress;
              } else {
                this.state.progress(false);
              }
              this.setState({ progress });
            }, 500);
          }, 1500)
        );
      }
```

1. The `setInterval` shouldn't start in the callback for setting the state - it doesn't relate to the state setting and causes confusion.
2. there's no need to create a local variable called `progress` here.  It leads to confusion and bugs, and offers no advantages.  Instead, use your component state as the source of truth.
3. this statement doesn't do anything except silently state the value of this.state.progress:

```js
              if (progress <= 100) {
                this.state.progress;
              } //...
```

4. As above, this statement is the source of your error:

```js
              } else {
                this.state.progress(false);
              }
```

What is the goal of this statement?

5. Your `setInterval` has no exit condition or cleanup function, meaning it will run forever.  One way to address this is to use a recursive `setTimeout` instead.

---

Here's some suggestions for a revision:

```js
      // in constructor - hold the progress timeout in state so you can clear it later
      this.state = {
        progress: 0,
        progressTimeout: undefined,
      };

      startProgressIndicators() {
        // define the recursive progress-setting function
        const setProgress = () => {
          const newProgress = this.state.progress + Math.random();
          // exit condition - this will stop the function once you reach 100
          if (newProgress >= 100) {
            this.setState({ progress: 100 });
            return;
          }
          // now you know your progress is < 100.  Run another setTimeout to increase it 
          this.setState({
            progress: newProgress,
            // setTimeout returns a number that can be used to clear the timeout, so we store it in state
            progressTimeout: setTimeout(setProgress, 500),
          });
        }
        // start the function after an initial delay
        setTimeout(setProgress, 1500);
      }

      // clear the timeout if one is running when the user navigates away
      // from the component.  This prevents a memory leak
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.state.progressTimeout);
      }
```

Comment: No problem. If the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Or if you solve it your own way, feel free to answer it yourself and accept that!